# Socket.io data to HTML text

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, socket.io

I get data like this that is logged in the console from a socket.io url which is triggered on certain events. Now all I would like to do is get specific data from that, like the amount.

I've tried so many things to just get the **amount** value and anything else, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the only code I'm using in my .php file.

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
  const socketToken = 'mytokenishere'; //Socket token from /socket/token end point
  //Connect to socket
  const streamlabs = io(`https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=${socketToken}`);
  //Perform Action on event
  streamlabs.on('event', (eventData) => {
    if (!eventData.for || eventData.for === 'streamlabs' && eventData.type === 'donation') {
      //code to handle donation events
      console.log(eventData.message);
    }
    if (eventData.for === 'twitch_account') {
      switch(eventData.type) {
        case 'follow':
          console.log(eventData.message);
          break;
        case 'subscription':
          //code to handle subscription events
          console.log(eventData.message);
          break;
        default:
          //default case
          console.log(eventData.message);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

I've tried doing things as `document.write(eventData.message);` but that returns `[object Object]`
I also tried `document.write(["0"].amount);` that returns `undefined`

I really appreciate all replies, thank you in advance if you know any solution!

EDIT: `document.write(JSON.stringify(eventData.message));` gives me

```
[{
    "isTest":true,
    "formatted_amount":"$87.00",
    "amount":87,
    "message":"This is a test donation for $87.00.",
    "currency":"USD",
    "from":"John",
    "from_user_id":1,
    "_id":"c3135e2c8011e545091f020f8378***"
}]
```

It looks like it's an object within an array, I need to figure out how to make it so it's only an object.

`document.write(eventData.message[0].from);
 document.write(eventData.message[0].formatted_amount);`
**results:** John $87.00

So it was very simple.. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try `eventData.message[0].message`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eventData.message[0]` should give you the base object you are looking for.

you have an array of objects being sent so you need to extract the first element of that array by accessing the index 0.

for instance
`eventData.message[0].amount` should be 48

Edit: I saw your edit where you state

> It looks like it's an object within an array, I need to figure out how
>   to make it so it's only an object.

Just create a new object to alias the name when you get it.

```
var data = eventData.message[0];
console.log(data.amount);
```

Comment: I swear I tried that at some point, but that works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to access to array items by index number.
For example:

```
console.log(eventData.message[0]) // log first item of eventdata's message
```